# BottomNavigationBarItem selectedItemColor is not working

Tags: flutter, dart, navigation, flutter-bottomnavigation

I need to change color of selected BottomNavigationBarItem to yellow, but it doesn't work.

It seems because i set BottomNavigationBarItem default colors as black, but otherwise they will be set as white, cause i created more than 3 items, and i don't know hot to fix them either

If you know how to fix this or white color bug, please inform me

```
            body: Center(
              child: _widgetopt.elementAt(_selind),
            ),
            bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
              type: BottomNavigationBarType.fixed,
              selectedItemColor: Colors.redAccent,
              backgroundColor: Colors.white,
              items: const <BottomNavigationBarItem>[
                BottomNavigationBarItem(
                    icon: Icon(
                      Icons.add_box_outlined,
                      color: Colors.black,
                    ),
                    label: ''),
                BottomNavigationBarItem(
                    icon: Icon(
                      Icons.location_on_outlined,
                      color: Colors.black,
                    ),
                    label: ''),
                BottomNavigationBarItem(
                    icon: Icon(
                      Icons.heart_broken_outlined,
                      color: Colors.black,
                    ),
                    label: ''),
                BottomNavigationBarItem(
                    icon: Icon(
                      Icons.person_outline_outlined,
                      color: Colors.black,
                    ),
                    label: ''),
              ],
              currentIndex: _selind,
              onTap: OnBeingTapped,
            ),
          ),
          title: 'Stadium',
        );
      }
    }
```

Rest of code:

```
class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  int _selind = 0;

  List<Widget> _widgetopt = <Widget>[
    Text('Index 1'),
    Text('Index 2'),
    Text('Index 3'),
    Text('Index 4'),
  ];

  void OnBeingTapped(int index) {
    setState(() {
      _selind = index;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text(
            'Стадионы',
            style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
          ),
          backgroundColor: Colors.white,
          toolbarHeight: 100,
          actions: [
            IconButton(
                onPressed: () {},
                icon: Icon(
                  Icons.menu_outlined,
                  color: Colors.black,
                )),
            IconButton(
                onPressed: () {},
                icon: Icon(
                  Icons.text_rotation_down_outlined,
                  color: Colors.black,
                )),
          ],
        ),
```

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to add `selectedItemColor` property of `BottomNavigationBarItem` widget. Just add below line in your code and you'll be able to see selected item color yellow from black.

```
    currentIndex: _selind,
    selectedItemColor: Colors.yellow,  // Add this line :)
    onTap: OnBeingTapped,
```